# MAX6675 gives a climbing reading

Tags: sensors, library

I am using a [MAX6675 board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M5CT365) and a k-type thermal couple to measure temp. The problem is even when running the example the temp value keeps climbing.

```
MAX6675 test
27.25
C = 27.25
F = 130.10
109.00
C = 218.00
F = 816.80
872.00
C = 1744.00
F = 2624.00
832.00
C = nan
F = nan
512.75
C = nan
F = nan
```

I am using the `max6675.h` library. Is there a way to fix this?

```
#include "max6675.h"

int thermoDO = 4;
int thermoCS = 5;
int thermoCLK = 6;

MAX6675 thermocouple(thermoCLK, thermoCS, thermoDO);
int vccPin = 3;
int gndPin = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // use Arduino pins 
  pinMode(vccPin, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(vccPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(gndPin, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(gndPin, LOW);

  Serial.println("MAX6675 test");
  // wait for MAX chip to stabilize
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  // basic readout test, just print the current temp

   Serial.print("C = "); 
   Serial.println(thermocouple.readCelsius());
   Serial.print("F = ");
   Serial.println(thermocouple.readFahrenheit());

   delay(1000);
}
```

edit: Added code (https://github.com/adafruit/MAX6675-library/blob/master/examples/serialthermocouple/serialthermocouple.pde)

Comment: Code? Wiring? ...?

Comment: I think your house is on fire. Or maybe your code is incorrect, but it's impossible to say when you haven't provided it to us.

Comment: The output does not look like it came from this sketch, quite apart from the values it prints. Your loop() function is coded to sample and print 2 lines every second: "C = .... \n" "F = .... \n", yet the output you showed has another line preceding each pair. Are you saying the sketch (or the library) is producing 3 lines where only 2 are coded?

Comment: I added a line that was just C= thermocouple.readCelsius() Serial.print (C)

Comment: Please provide a picture of your wiring, or at the very least confirm that the pins `GND`, `VCC`, `DO`, `CS` and `CLK` do indeed go to data pins `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and `6` respectively - as declared in your code. I assume this is AdaFruit's version of the library? If this all checks out, then it's almost certainly hardware: the thermocouple, the MAX6675, or the Arduino itself.

Comment: Check the sensor wiring. The return value NAN indicates that "no thermocouple attached". https://github.com/adafruit/MAX6675-library/blob/master/max6675.cpp#L38

Comment: I can confirm that the pins do match and I am using the AdaFruit library ( most current one I could download from using library manager)

Comment: After test some other K-type thermal couples on this I am now thinking I just got a bad board. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After test some other K-type thermal couples on this I am now thinking I just got a bad board. I was able to order a new one and it worked without issue